# Scanned image does not appear in PDF

Tags: floats

This is my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,onecolumn]{report}

\usepackage{pdfpages}%for inserting pdf thesis declarations
\usepackage{graphicx}%for inserting pdf thesis declarations

\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------Preamble 1--------------------------------------------------------------%
\newpage
\clearpage
%\pagestyle{plain}


%%%%%%%%%%\textbf{\large Statement of Originality}
\includepdf[pages={1}, pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{myscan1.pdf}

%--------------------------------------------------------------Preamble 2 Statement--------------------------------------------------------------%
\newpage
\clearpage
%\pagestyle{plain}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{myscanimage.jpg}
  \caption{A boat.}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: The scanned image]

Comment: Try with a minimal document … You know, just a few lines, adding the scanned image. Your code has at least a 100 lines that have nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Ingmar, the problem is I dont know which one is needed, or which is the problem.

Comment: Really? Try `\documentclass{report}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}\includegraphics{myscanimage.jpg}\end{document}` to get you started. if it doesn't work, check out the logfile.

Comment: @Ingmar, I shortened the code, please help

Comment: show the log-file of your example.

Comment: What is a log-file? is it the file ending with ".synctex"

Comment: To find the log file: if your latex file is called  say `foo.tex`, then the log file will be `foo.log` and will be in the same folder where `foo.tex` is.

Comment: So what's not working? `\includepdf[width=\pagewidth,pages={1}]{example.pdf}` worked without problems.

Comment: @Nasser, my folder has only 3 items, (1) the code, (2)".synctex" file and (3) the pdf

Comment: @Ingmar Let me emphasize that it fails only with SCANNED pdf or images. You can try with my scanned image and it wont appear

Comment: Right. Sounds like a potential issue with the file, then? Not all that much we can do about it on our end, especially without having access to the file. As Ulrike suggested, the logfile might have more info.

Comment: @ingmar I already uploaded the image. I suspect that it is the scanning that changes the format of the file. I tried scan and save as jpg or pdf; neither works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer, simply because the comment thread has gotten long enough and doesn't offer sufficient options in term of formatting.

I have used this code on TexLive 2022:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=\textheight]{SozLJ}
\end{document}
```

using your image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SozLJ.jpg) and it compiled fine. There seems to be nothing special about this file.

Please try yourself, and check the logfile if it does not work.

Comment: I can't compile it. It says 
"<myscanimage.jpg, id=1, 580.3281pt x 827.9733pt>

! Undefined control sequence.
\Gin@@eheight ->\pageheight 

l.6 ...degraphics[height=\pageheight]{myscanimage}".


And, there is no ".log" file in my folder.

Comment: I suspect Ingmar used lualatex, replace `\pageheight` with `\textheight` @SphericalMoments

Comment: I can compile it with "\textheight" but the image still doesn't appear

Comment: I am sorry, yes, I did use LuaLaTeX. Fixed.

Comment: So what are you getting. White page? Nothing? No errors? What software are you using, anyway? At least now we know there's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: @SphericalMoments download https://i.stack.imgur.com/SozLJ.jpg and test that (which is what others will be using) That is the file you uploaded but imgur will have normalised it so it will not be identical internally.

Comment: I downloaded the SozLZ from the web and compile using that. I get a empty page (but with page number "1" below). No errors. I m using Texworks, and the option "pdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex"

Comment: Can you please show me your output, the pdf that you get?

Comment: Ok, it works now. The image does not appear in the pdf which is opened alongside the code. However, it appears if I open the pdf (without the code). That is good enough for me. Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: Sounds like a (configuration?) issue with  Texworks … Glad you got it to work, though.